# Getting 0 value for Items and Size within PowerShell Get-ContentSearch when using a Where query

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of content searches within Microsoft Purview all created with New-ComplianceSearch then edited within the UI and ran.  The name of each starts with a different subject and I'm trying to get the total items and size for each one.  First I search with a wild card to get one of my lists:

`Get-ComplianceSearch | where-object { $_.Name -like 'Spam Emails*' }`

and I get the correct list:

```
Name                           RunBy  JobEndTime           Status
----                           -----  ----------           ------
Spam Emails - From xxxxxx      Admin  2/28/2024 2:34:41 PM Completed
Spam Emails - From yyyyyy      Admin  2/28/2024 2:44:12 PM Completed
Spam Emails - From zzzzzz      Admin  2/28/2024 2:44:39 PM Completed
```

Now I want to get just the Name, Item, and Size so I do this:

```
Get-ComplianceSearch | where-object { $_.Name -like 'Spam Emails*' } | Select-Object Name,Items,Size
```

But I get this:

```
Name                         Items Size
----                         ----- ----
Spam Emails - From xxxxxx     0    0
Spam Emails - From yyyyyy     0    0
Spam Emails - From zzzzzz     0    0
```

But if I look at a individual one using this:

```
Get-ComplianceSearch -Identity 'Spam Emails - From xxxxxx' | Select-Object Name,Items,Size
```

I get this:

```
Name                       Items       Size
----                       -----       ----
Spam Emails - From xxxxxx   946    48576297
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The Manual™](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-compliancesearch)

> To improve the performance of this cmdlet, some compliance search properties aren't returned if you don't specify the identity of the compliance search. These properties are:
>
> - Items
> - Size
> - SuccessResults
> - NumBindings
> - ExchangeLocation
> - SharePointLocation
> - OneDriveLocation

Comment: I don't know how I missed that and that's unfortunate.  I guess I can write a multi line PowerShell script to do a ForEach or something.  Was really hoping to have a single liner do it.

Comment: I honestly would have expected it being in a dedicated "Output" section, so I understand how easily would be to miss it

Comment: I accepted your answer and also posted my own.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it can't be done as a one liner but it can be done as a ForEach:

```
ForEach ($name in (Get-ComplianceSearch | where-object { $_.Name -like 'Spam Emails*' }))
{
    Get-ComplianceSearch -Identity $name | Select Name, Items, Size
}
```

And this gets me the correct result although I need to do some formatting:

```
Name                  Items       Size
----                  -----       ----
Spam Emails - xxxxxxx  1952 4259327202
Spam Emails - yyyyyyy   675  133000915
Spam Emails - zzzzzzz   302  523784251
```